# Understanding math: transformation world coordinates to view coordinates

Tags: opengl, math, matrix, coordinates, transform

I am trying to understand the math behind the transformation from world coordinates to view coordinates.
This is the formula to calculate the matrix in view coordinates:

[image]

and here is an example, that should normally be correct...: 
[image]

where b = width of the viewport and h= the height of the viewport

But I just don't know how to calculate the R matrix. How do you get Ux, Uy, Uz, Vx, Vy, etc... ? U,v and, n is the coordinatesystem fixed to the camera. And the camera is at position X0, Y0, Z0.

Comment: What are U, V, and N?

Comment: Probably surface-x, surface-y and normal.

Comment: Those are unit vector components from the point of view of the camera.  They define a 3D coordinate system with the lens as the origin.

Answer (score 2):

The matrix T is applied first. It translates some world coordinate **P** by *minus* the camera coordinate (call it **C**), giving the *relative* coordinate of **P** (call this **Q**) with respect to the camera (**Q** = **P** - **C**), in the *world* axes orientation.

The matrix R is then applied to **Q**. It performs a rotation to obtain the coordinates of **Q** in the *camera*'s axes.

- **u** is the horizontal view axis
- **v** is the vertical view axis
- **n** is the view direction axis

(all three should be normalized)

Multiplying R with **Q** :

1. multiplying with the first line of R gives DOT(**Q**, **u**). This returns the component of **Q** projected onto **u**, which is the horizontal view coordinate.
2. the second line gives DOT(**Q**, **v**), which similar to above gives the vertical view coordinate.
3. the third line gives DOT(**Q**, **n**), which is the depth view coordinate.

A diagram:
[image]

BTW These are NOT screen/viewport coordinates! They are just the coordinates in the camera/view frame. To get the perspective-corrected coordinate another matrix (the projection matrix) needs to be applied.

Comment: Could you elaborate using the provided example please. This would clarify a few things..

Comment: I have difficulties to know how to make this 4x4 rotation matrix R

Comment: @privetDruzzia I already told you how to make R - use the normalized camera axes u,v and n and sub into the matrix expression you have for R. You question was "how to get Ux, Uv etc", but you should _already have them_ if you want to calculate anything to do with the viewpoint

Comment: I have no u,v and n coordinates I only know that the camera is at position (4;0;4). I understand your explanation (I think, thx for it). But I just don't know how to start

Comment: @privetDruzia you _must_ have at least two vectors to define the camera's orientation; the position is _not_ one of them. I can't help you if you have no information about the camera at all; which direction does it face, and is it tilted or straight up ?

Comment: The coordinates of the camera are given by P1 and P2 and its looking at the origin

Comment: @privetDruzia why are there two points? is the camera upright?

Comment: Nothing special it s just that I have to calculate it once in the first position and once in the other position. Well... that s a good question I don't know whether it is upright. Is there a way to determine this? All the info I have is on the picture above unfortunately

Comment: @privetDruzia I'm afraid not man - you have to _know_ that to calculate the camera; but it's _usually_ upright